# Odd jquery html behavior

Tags: jquery, html

```
$('.editTime').click(function(){
            var thisId = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
            alert($('#'+thisId).html());
            $('#'+thisId).html("Some Text");
            alert($('#'+thisId).html());
    });


 <td class='editTime' id='someId'><a href='#'>Some Original Text</a></td>
```

When a user clicks the link in the td, the data in the cell should change from "Some Original Text" to "Some Text".   In the browser window it does not change.  The alerts however do show the new data in the cell.  Any idea whats going on here?

Comment: use  `$(this).attr('id');` with `$('#'+thisId).find('a').html("Some Text");`

Comment: or try direct $(this).find('a').text('Some Text); simply

Comment: `$('.editTime').click(function(){ ...` but your `<a>` is not `$('.editTime')`, that's your `<td>` :/ so it's not the jQuery which is odd, it just you're being not careful

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('.editTime').click(function(){
    $(this).find('a').text("Some Text");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Theme Simply Me</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#someId').on('click', function () {
                $('#someId a').text('Some Text');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr><td class='editTime' id='someId'><a href='#'>Some Original Text</a></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you click on the **td**,  **a** tag is also being clicked so you have to use **e.preventDefault()** function to prevent the page to load again.

So the code can be written like this

```
$('.editTime').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).find('a').html('Some text')
})
```

**HTML should contain proper table and tr tags.**

For example

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='editTime' id='someId'><a href='#'>Some Original Text</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Check the working **[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/xv098m9o/).**